# Any pointers on using C# and the MSBuild object model to build .Net assemblies?

Tags: c#, msbuild

OK, I'll confess I just HATE MSBuild files, and would rather control the process of building.Net C# / Website code via a nice language with actual decision structures etc, like...ohh, I know, C#.

I know there is an MSBuild object model since that's what you use to write custom tasks.

Any pointers on using that doing what I want? Not having much luck wording my searches (or possibly I am just crazy and nobody does it this way)

Comment: I personally think it would be a huge waste of time to write your "makefiles" in C# (as you partially suggest), but you know, nothing stops you from doing just that. You don't need MSBuild at all. Just control the build process by doing stuff like: `Process.Start("csc.exe …");` etc. (Again: I would definitely *not* recommend this. But it's possible if that's what you want.)

Comment: It's the XML. Huge, hard to follow - especially the more other targets files are included - does the last one in still override if they contradict? No support for proper decision structures. It seems daft (to me) to mix up data (settings) and directives (tasks).  kind reminds me of the ickiness of the way ASP mixed functionality and presentation....

Comment: It might just be one of those personal preference things, but I'll almost bet that in 5 years time (if not sooner) you'll see a move to programming builds via code or it moving more into the IDE (as deployments have....). I just seem to always be building stuff (or wanting it) that takes in 5-10 years to become all the rage and then gets built-in :-).

Answer (score 4):

I am doing some custom tasks for our build jobs at the moment, and I have found the book [Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=12999&locale=en-us) very useful. It has several examples on how to customize the build process using custom tasks.

Comment: got that one. and we have some custom tasks already, so I have been looking at that section.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a task doesn't have anything to do with the sequencing of the tasks as directed by a .targets file.  You can execute tasks from a C# program as well, use their Execute() method.  You'll probably find this to be largely an exercise in property assigning, tasks normally have a *lot* of them.  After a while, you'll wonder why you wouldn't just use a data file.  In xml format.

Comment: We use tasks to pull build related information from a database, but I guess in many other cases you might as well just use data files.

Comment: that sounds nearer my type of thinking.